# Clipping in/with Sentinel Hub API

Tags: clip, extents, sentinel-2, sentinel, sentinel-hub

Is it possible clipping a Sentinel-2 image from Sentinel Hub with circular boundaries?
In Sentinel Hub documentation, I only found support to Bound Box (BBox) AOI that close an image in a retangular clipping.

Comment: Images aren't circular. You can mask out the rasterization of a circle in an image, but it still won't be circular.

Answer (score 1):

As Vince has said you cannot create a "perfect" circle using a raster as pixels are not circular. However, using the Sentinel Hub Process API, you can return an image with circular boundaries.

Below is an example of how to do this in Python:

```py
from sentinelhub import (
    SentinelHubRequest,
    DataCollection,
    MimeType,
    CRS,
    Geometry
)

evalscript = """
//VERSION=3

function setup() {
  return {
    input: ["B02", "B03", "B04"],
    output: { bands: 3 }
  };
}

function evaluatePixel(sample) {
  return [2.5 * sample.B04, 2.5 * sample.B03, 2.5 * sample.B02];
}
"""
geometry = Geometry(geometry={"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[12.483395,41.903044],[12.478245,41.8987],[12.48185,41.897422],[12.487342,41.898316],[12.488887,41.900233],[12.483395,41.903044]]]}, crs=CRS.WGS84)

request = SentinelHubRequest(
    evalscript=evalscript,
    input_data=[
        SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
            data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A,          
            time_interval=('2023-03-07', '2023-04-07'),          
        ),
    ],
    responses=[
        SentinelHubRequest.output_response('default', MimeType.JPG),
    ],
    geometry=geometry,
    size=[512, 363.384],
    config=config
)

response = request.get_data()
```

To insert your area of interest, you can replace the geojson in the geometry parameter in the example. This will return the data for your geometry instead of a bounding box. As I don't know your other parameters, make sure to update them too.

I would also recommend trying out our [Request Builder](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/requests-builder/) application, which is a great sandbox for exploring the Sentinel Hub APIs.